speed up inserts on big postgres database
we are currently running into a bit of an issue with insertion speed into one of our tables.
The table holds events from users and in peak times we reach a few hundreds events per second and during those times the execution times spikes hard.
Between 1 and about 250 inserts per second we have response times of 30ms, but at 300 inserts per second this already spikes to 1.7 seconds and after 450 requests per second inserts are timing out.
The table looks something like this:
CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq
    AS bigint START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE some_table (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass),
    "created" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    ...
    "externalid1" int8,
    "externalid2" int8,
    "sessionid" int8,
    ...
    "requestuuid" text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT "fk1" FOREIGN KEY ("externalid1") REFERENCES "other_table_1"("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk2" FOREIGN KEY ("externalid2") REFERENCES "other_table_2"("id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

The insert-query I used for testing is very simple like this:
INSERT INTO some_table (created,...,sessionid,...) 
VALUES (NOW(),...,%d,...)

with the sessionid being a newly random generated number for every insert.
The execution-plan (with EXPLAIN ANALYZE) for this query looks like this:
Insert on some_table  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=0.301..0.301 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=272) (actual time=0.090..0.090 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.075 ms
Trigger for constraint fk1 on some_table_3: time=0.894 calls=1
Trigger for constraint fk2 on some_table_3: time=0.385 calls=1
Execution Time: 1.829 ms

Edit: Another execution-plan with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) ... while a load of 200 inserts / second is running.
Insert on some_table  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=0.060..0.060 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=272) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.032 ms
Trigger for constraint fk1 on some_table_1: time=0.129 calls=1
Trigger for constraint fk2 on some_table_1: time=0.059 calls=1
Execution Time: 0.272 ms

We already looked into the following possible solutions:

Batch up inserts: not possible because the events are very important and after a user got a success message they cannot be lost and in case of a crash all events in the current batch could be lost.
Remove Foreign-Keys and Indices: Indices are required for the processing of the data since the table normally holds about 300 million entries from the last 30 days. Removing the foreign keys would be something of a last resort because those are used for cleaning up old entries
Partition the table: Since the session-id is a number identifying the users session we tried to partition by session-id with 10 partition-tables using this:

CREATE TABLE some_table (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass),
    "created" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    ...
    "externalid1" int8,
    "externalid2" int8,
    "sessionid" int8,
    ...
    "requestuuid" text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT "fk1" FOREIGN KEY ("externalid1") REFERENCES "other_table_1"("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk2" FOREIGN KEY ("externalid2") REFERENCES "other_table_2"("id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id,sessionid)
) PARTITION BY HASH(sessionid);

CREATE TABLE some_table_0 PARTITION OF some_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 10, REMAINDER 0);
CREATE TABLE some_table_1 PARTITION OF some_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 10, REMAINDER 1);
CREATE TABLE some_table_2 PARTITION OF some_table FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 10, REMAINDER 2);
...

INSERT INTO some_table
SELECT * FROM some_table_old;

In contrast to what we expected this even slowed it all down. Our best guess is that the overhead on partitions is heavier on the load than the improvement we get because of the smaller tables.

Upgrade Database: we are currently running on pg-13 but migrating it to pg-16.3 did not bring any noticeable improvements.

After trying all of this we are a bit puzzled on what to try next. Any ideas?

Maybe dba.stackexchange.com has an option, but I like option 2 ("Remove Foreign-Keys and Indices")

Your question is missing key details such as the table(s) definition, insert queries, exec plan, how many users are inserting into that table in parallel, how many queries per user per second, etc. Also, the calculation is wrong somewhere... you talk about 450 queries max / second (as I understand, 1 record at a time since you claim you can't batch inserts) but "300 million entries from the last 24h-36h" would mean an average between 2300 to 3500 records inserted/sec. What's up with the discrepancy?

Please post a correct example, current code is missing you definition of the sequence, and is showing an incorrect CREATE TABLE statement for a partitioned table.  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/lzujrRR9 )

When you tested option 2, did it work?

"Batch up inserts: not possible because the events are very important and after a user got a success message they cannot be lost"  If it times out, they are also lost.  Or maybe if the client crashes while waiting for a response.  Or if the internet glitches.  By not batching, you are paying a cost but are probably not actually getting the gaurantee you think you are.  Is this part of some 2-phase commit system?

@Atmo I added some more information on the table an insert to the post. But that part regarding the 3.5k entries per second is strange, I need to double check the numbers there.

@Luuk updated the post

@jjanes yes, I tested it yesterday and what is really puzzling is that removing the foreignkeys seems to slow down the whole process. On my test yesterday the execution-times started to go above 30ms with 300 Executions/Second and for the normal inserts we got to an average of 1.8s and after dropping the foreign keys we got to an average of 8.6s... that is definitely not what I expected

@jjanes regarding batching up inserts, the thing is that we have a transaction running whenever a user adds an event. That means the user only gets a successful response if the event is actually persisted.
Lets say we batch the events up, then the user could get a success message which indicates to him that the event was persisted, but after that the services crashes and the event was lost.
If the connection crashes then we are fine if the event is lost. It is just important that it is not lost after we confirmed to the user that it was persisted.

I am just thinking maybe it is also an issue with how I am testing the load. I am using a golang-script for this which looks something like this:
https://gist.github.com/Neokil/842f64ad244248b4ec27f36688d2002b

@Atmo I just double checked and the 24h window was a wrong assumption on my side. This is what was setup on my test-environment but on the prod where the numbers are from it is 30 days. In that case the numbers make sense again because then we have an average of 100 inserts/second

It's not clear to me what "a transaction running whenever a user adds an event" or "successful response if the event is actually persisted" mean. Your approach right now is to explore how you can improve performance without breaking that response mechanism. A combination of several of these improvements may work but it could be many things to implement and it looks like this was a dead end. IMHO, you should also explore everything and anything to improve performance, then if a single option works well, think of a way to "restore" the responses.

The plan you show seems to be for when there was no other load on the server.  Could you do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) instead and do it when there is considerable (but not overwhelming) load, e.g. when the response time is about 30ms?

I think your measurements without FK in place were taken after the point where the performance collapsed.  But by then, the performance is chaotic, and I don' think measurements mean very much. You need to look at whether you moved the point where the collapse happens, not at what happens after that point has already been exceeded.

@jjanes I added the new explain to the question

Your new execution under load is even faster than the previous one.  I wonder if the bottleneck is entirely in the client and has nothing to do with the database itself?
